# Powershell - Search for files from list and copy to new directory

Tags: arrays, powershell, copy

I have a script I'm using to search for files through directories and sub-directories.  It works great.

I need to modify it, to **copy any  files** from the directory it resides in to another directory.

The problem with my script (below) is that everything is held in arrays and I cannot figure out how to modify it to behave the way I need it to.

Can someone take a look at this and point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
-Ron

```
#List containing file names must be wilcarded FILE.*
#Parent folder (Where to begin search)
 $folder = 'C:\Workspace\discovery-jumpstart\src'
#Missing Artifacts Folder (Where Text file resides)
 $Dir2 = 'C:\Workspace\discovery-jumpstart'
#Text File Name
 $files=Get-Content $Dir2\MISSING_BMS.txt
   
 cd \
 cd $folder
    
 Write-Host "Starting Folder: $folder"
 $folderFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder -File).Name
   foreach ($f in $files) {
     if ($folderFiles -contains $f) { 
        Write-Host "File $f was found." -foregroundcolor green
      } 
     else { 
        Write-Host "File $f was not found!" -foregroundcolor red 
      }
}
```

Ok.  I found a script while searching the net.  I altered it slightly and ran it.  It works flawlessly.  The only issue...  I do not understand it at all.
Would one of the guru's here break this down and explain why this works?

Thanks,

-Ron

```
#Dir to search
$source = 'C:\Temp'
#Text file with search for members
$file_source ="C:\Results_Found_Files_Scan.txt'
#where to copy the matched files
$target = 'C:\Clients' 
get-content $file_source | 
ForEach-Object { get-childitem -Path $source -Recurse -Filter "$_" } | 
Copy-Item -Destination $target
```

Comment: Why do you need to change into that directory? Throw in another `foreach` loop to iterate through your files from `$files`, or you can use a comparison operator such as `-contains`.

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala
I'm not sure I follow.  Add a -Contains instead of -like?

Comment: Yes. `if($folderfiles -contains $f){...` that's because, you're comparing a whole array to a single file and would need the proper comparison operator for that. You should also be able to us `-in` as long as you swap the condition variables.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Probably best if you post that as answer

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala
I'm trying to put together a working script so I can show my work and hopefully a solution.

Comment: @user3166462, what part would you like explained? You are grabbing the content of the file `$file_source ="C:\Results_Found_Files_Scan.txt'` and foreach *object* (line - or - name) grabbed from the file, recurse (go/read through) each folder/item filtering for the content (line - or name) that's currently in the pipeline using `$_`, and copy it to the destination specified.

Comment: No prob at all!

Answer (score 0):

The part below needs to be modified to after the `Write-Host "File $f was found." -foregroundcolor green` you can use the `Copy-Item` command.

```
if ($folderFiles -like $f) { 
        Write-Host "File $f was found." -foregroundcolor green
        Copy-Item (Copy-Item command and the parameters, you would like to use.)
      }
```